# Continuous time markov chains, is this step by step example correct

Tags: statistics, markov-chains, markov-process

I have some questions regarding CTMC... and most importantly whether the step-by-step example I provide below is correct. My main sources about CTMC are: ([[1]](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-CTMC.pdf), and [[2]](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~stat455/lecturenotes/set5.pdf)).

Let's assume 3 possible states $S = {1, 2, 3}$. There are the following data instances $D = {d_1, d_2, d_3, d_4}$ from which I want to model as a CTMC. In parenthesis the time spent at the state before transiting to the next.

$
d_1 = 1(3min) \rightarrow 2(3min) \rightarrow 3\\
d_2 = 1(8min) \rightarrow 2(12min) \rightarrow 3\\
d_3 = 1(2min) \rightarrow 3\\
d_4 = 2(2min) \rightarrow 3
$

The main question(s) I want to ask and answer from the CTMC is:

- **Problem:** What is the probability of transiting from state $i$ to state $j$ given that $s$ time has elapsed since entering state $i$?

So to form the CTMC I start with the *embedded transition matrix* for $D$ which is:

$
p_{ij} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2/3 & 1/3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$

Now the next step is to calculate the rates. From [1, p3] it says that *"Each time state i is visited, the chain spends, on average, $E(Hi) = 1/a_i$ units of time there before moving on"*. From what I understand $a_i$ is the set of rates for state $i$, also denoted in other texts as $\lambda_i$ or $v_i$, for example an operator receives 2 calls in an hour, hence $a_i = 1$ call in half an hour. However, I am not sure how to calculate this from the above data $D$. But, I can calculate the average time spent at each state and then from the above equation, solving for $a_i = 1 / E(H_i)$ I can obtain these rates...

$E(H_i) = \begin{bmatrix}4.33 & 5.66 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, denoting with 0 the terminal (consume) state.

Hence,

$a_i = \begin{bmatrix}0.23 & 0.18 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, again 0 is for consume state.

- **Q1:** Is this valid?
- **Q2:** Given that in this way I assume that the probability distribution of time spent is an exponential distribution, I lose the true variance of the actual distribution as the variance of the exponential distribution is the same as the mean... Is this OK? Is there any other way?
- **Q3:** How can terminal/consume states be represented?

Again from [1, p3] I can now compute the transition rate matrix (infinitesimal generator) $Q$:

$Q_{ij} = -a_i$, if $i==j$

$Q_{ij} = a_i * p_{ij}$, if $i != j$

$
Q = \begin{bmatrix}
-0.23 & 0.15 & 0.08\\
0 & -0.18 & 0.18\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$

- **Q4:** Although [1, p3] states that $Q_{ii} = -a_i$, [2, p227] says that $Q_{ii} = 0$. Which one is correct then?

Now that we know $Q$, from [1, p2] I can calculate $P_{ij}(t)$ as follows:

$P_{ij}(t) = e^{Qt}$ (from what I read there are a number of ways to compute that and I can use a numerical software that implements them)

- **Q5:** I assume $t = s$, ie the elapsed time since entering state $i$
- **Q6:** Why do I need to calculate the complete matrix $P_{ij}(t)$ if I am interested in one particular ${ij}$. Is there any way to calculate that.
- **Q7:** I read in [2, p.228] that if the process can be modelled as a Poisson process then the solution is: $P_{ij}(t) = \dfrac{(\lambda_i t)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda_i t}$, where $k$ is the number of events in an interval of length t, which in my case above is $1$. Can I assume that the above process is a Poisson process?
- **Q8:** And lastly is everything I have explained in the above step-by-step example correct?

Thank you the most for your time reading this and if you can provide any answers to my questions.

Comment: *What is the probability [...] given [...] time has elapsed since entering state?* In time-homogeneous CTMCs of the kind you consider here, the transition times are exponentially distributed, so if you know the time spend in some state, you don't have any new information regarding even *when* the jump will happen, let alone the distribution of the landing point.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... I understand your comment, but what I am trying to find out is exactly $P_{ij}(t)$, i.e. what is the probability of a transition from $i$ to $j$ at elapsed time $t$ since entering state $i$. I am not trying to predict the distribution of the landing point or find any new information regarding when the jump will happen.

Comment: Why would it be possible to model this process by a CTMC?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Cause I would like to find $P_{ij}(t)$ from continuous time data and CTMC does exactly that. Is there any violation or error in the above example?

Comment: The construction you have in mind (if I understand it correctly) violates some properties shared by any Markovian structure. There is no $P_{ij}$ in your context because knowing the state one is at currently does not suffice to determine the future dynamics. (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the best strategy for a problem of this kind would be to proceed in two steps:

1. Fit a continuous time Markov chain model to the data by estimating the (infinitesimal) generator $Q$.
2. Using the estimated generator and the Kolmogorov backward equations, find the probability that a Markov chain following the fitted model transitions from state $i$ to state $j$ in time $s$.

The generator can be estimated directly, no need to first go via the embedded Markov chain.  A summary of methods (considering the more complicated case of missing data) can for example be found in [Metzner *et al.* (2007)](http://www.mathematik.uni-karlsruhe.de/ianm3/~jahnke/media/medijasc2007.pdf).  While estimating the generator is possible using the observations you list in your example, you have very little data available: Your data contains 6 observed transitions (the usable data being the time until the transition and the pair of states).  From this data you need to estimate the six transition rates which make up the off-diagonal elements of the generator.  Since the amount of data is not much larger than the number of parameters to be estimated, the resulting estimate may not be very reliable.  In particular, with so little data it will be difficult to know whether unobserved transitions are impossible, or just have not been observed by chance.

The general form for the generator of a continuous time Markov chain with three states is
$$
Q = \begin{pmatrix}
  -a_1 & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
  a_{21} & -a_2 & a_{23} \\
  a_{31} & a_{32} & -a_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where the diagonal elements satisfy $a_i = \sum_{j\neq i}a_{ij}$.
The easiest way for estimating $Q$ may be using the maximum likelihood estimate (MLE): from equation (13) in [Metzner *et al.* (2007)](http://www.mathematik.uni-karlsruhe.de/ianm3/~jahnke/media/medijasc2007.pdf) we know that the MLE for $a_{ij}$ is given by
$$
  \hat a_{ij} = \frac{N_{ij}}{R_i}
$$
where $N_{ij}$ is the number of observed transitions from $i$ to $j$ and $R_i$ is the total time spent in state $i$ by the observed process.  With your data the estimates are $\hat a_{12} = 2 / (3+8+2) = 0.154$, $\hat a_{13} = 1 / (3+8+2) = 0.077$, $\hat a_{21} = 0 / (2+3+12) = 0$, $\hat a_{23} = 3 / (2+3+12) = 0.176$.  This seems compatible with the results you obtained.  (There is a small complication here, because the cited article assumes that the Markov chain is observed until a fixed time $T$ rather then until a certain jump, but it is easy to check that this distinction does not matter for computing the MLE.)

The data you give lists no observations for the system being in state 3, so no estimates of $a_{31}$ and $a_{32}$ are possible from the given data.  If the system has been observed to stay in state 3 for a time without making a transition, then $R_3$ is positive and we would get the MLEs $\hat a_{31} = \hat a_{32} = 0$.  In this case, state 3 would be absorbing (represented by a row of zeros in the generator) and the generator would be the one given by you above.

Finally, using the Kolmogorov backward equations, it is possible to compute the transition probabilities for the fitted model.  From equation (14) in your first reference we know that the transition matrix over a time interval of length $s$ is given by
$$
P(s) = \exp(sQ)
$$
where $sQ$ is obtained by multiplying every element in $Q$ by $s$ and $\exp(sQ)$ is the matrix exponential.  The matrix exponential can be directly computed in many software packages (*e.g.* using `expm` in matlab), or "by hand" by diagonalising the matrix $sQ$.  The required probability that a Markov chain following the fitted model transitions from state $i$ to state $j$ in time $s$ can then be found in row $i$, column $j$ of the resulting matrix.

answers to your questions:

- **problem**: see above
- **Q1**: I believe your approach is valid but unnecessarily complicated
- **Q2**: You don't need to "assume" that the waiting times are exponential, this is automatically true in CTMC models.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Parameter_estimation) has a section about how to estimate the parameter of an exponential distribution.  (And I believe your approach coincides with the MLE, so should be valid.)
- **Q3**: terminal/consume states are represented as a row of zeros in the generator.
- **Q4**: the diagonal elements of the generator are always equal to the negative of the sum of all non-diagonal elements in the same row, *i.e.* they are equal to $-a_i$.  This may be 0 if the whole row is 0.
- **Q5**: this seems not to be a question
- **Q6**: I don't think there is a simple way to compute just one element of a matrix exponential.  The usual thing to do is to compute the whole matrix and then to pick out the elements you need.
- **Q7**: whether a Poisson process is a good model for your data depends mostly on the context and origin of your data.  Not though that Poisson processes can take arbitrarily large values, so if you know that you have three states a Poisson process is not a valid model to describe your data.
- **Q8**: I don't know.

Comment: This misses the fact that the model the OP has in mind cannot be Markov.

Comment: @Did, the OP explicitly states "... which I want to model as a CTMC", and to me it seems that the given data (six observed transitions between the states 1,2,3) could be very well modelled by a continuous time Markov chain.  Why do you think the OP's model "cannot be Markov"?

Comment: Say, because some transition probabilities (and transition times) from one state to another depend explicitly on the previous state (as explained in a comment posted several days before your answer).

Comment: @Did, I still don't understand your problem :(  For a CTMC it is allowed that the transitions (both the distribution of the holding times in a state and the distribution of the the next state) depend on the current state (see *e.g.* on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain): "future behaviour of the model ... depends [only] on the current state of the model ...").  And I don't see any mention of dependence on the value before the last jump in the questions, so a Markov model seems appropriate to me here.

Comment: The text mentions *three* different rates for the jump $2\to3$. A Markov chain could have at most one.

Comment: @Did, now I think I finally understand what you mean.  In my answer I took "data instances" to mean different observations of jumps (all governed by the same rate) rather than different rates.  In particular I took 3min, 12min and 2min to be three different observations of random holding times in state 2.  Do you think these are meant to be rates?  If so, shouldn't the unit be 1/time rather than time?

Comment: Only the OP could say (but they do not seem interested in explaining this). In any case, rates cannot be measured in minutes.

Comment: @Did Thank you for your comments. These are not rates. These are the times that a state has spent each time it was observed. Jochen's last comment is describes exactly what they are.

Comment: @jochen Since system does not allow me to add more than one at user... apologies for repetition of comment. Thank you for your comments. These are not rates. These are the times that a state has spent each time it was observed. Jochen's last comment is describes exactly what they are.